# Rails: Setting Model Attributes to Attributes from Another Model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I am a little unsure of how to ask this so I apologize for the clunky explanation.

I have three models, User, Waterusage and Goals

```
class Goal < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :user
end

class Waterusage < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable,
      has_one :waterusage, :dependent => :destroy
      has_one :goals, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Waterusage is filled out first by users and then goals. Goals is the exactly same schema as waterusage, but uses a portion of the waterusage form and copies the remaining attributes from waterusage.

```
class Goal < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user



# before_validation :get_from_waterusage
  before_validation :calculate_totals

  def get_from_waterusage
    self.household_size = @waterusage.household_size
    self.swimming_pool = @waterusage.swimming_pool
    self.bathroom_sink_flow_rate = @waterusage.bathroom_sink_flow_rate
    self.low_flow_toilet = @waterusage.low_flow_toilet
    self.kitchen_sink_usage = @waterusage.kitchen_sink_usage
    self.kitchen_sink_flow_rate = @waterusage.kitchen_sink_flow_rate
    self.dishwasher_rate = @waterusage.dishwasher_rate
    self.dishwasher_multiplier = @waterusage.dishwasher_multiplier
    self.laundry_rate = @waterusage.laundry_rate
    self.laundry_multiplier = @waterusage.laundry_multiplier
    self.lawn_size = @waterusage.lawn_size
    self.carwash_rate = @waterusage.carwash_rate
    self.carwash_multiplier = @waterusage.carwash_multiplier
    self.miles = @waterusage.miles
    self.statewater = @waterusage.statewater
    self.percent_statewater = @waterusage.percent_statewater
    self.pet_cost = @waterusage.pet_cost
     end
    ...
    end
```

Here is the GoalsController

class GoalsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!

```
  def new
    @goal = goal.new
  end

  def create
    #@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @goal = current_user.create_goal(goal_params)
    redirect_to goal_result_path

  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @goal = @user.goal.find(params[:id])
    @goal.destroy
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  end

  def show
    @goal = goal.find(params[:id])
  end

  def results

    if current_user.goal.get_individual_total > 6000
      @temp = 6000
    else
      @temp = current_user.goal.get_individual_total
    end

    @goal = current_user.goal

  end

  private
    def goal_params
      params.require(:goal).permit(:household_size, :average_shower,
        :shower_flow_rate, :bath_rate, :bath_multiplier, 
        :bathroom_sink_usage,
        :bathroom_sink_flow_rate, :mellow, :low_flow_toilet, 
        :kitchen_sink_usage,
        :kitchen_sink_flow_rate, :dishwasher_rate, 
        :dishwasher_multiplier,
        :dishwasher_method, :laundry_rate, :laundry_multiplier, 
    :laundry_method,
        :greywater, :lawn_rate, :lawn_multiplier, :lawn_size, 
 :xeriscaping,
        :swimming_pool, :swimming_months, :carwash_rate, 
  :carwash_multiplier,
         :carwash_method, :miles, :statewater, :percent_statewater, 
 :shopping,
        :paper_recycling, :plastic_recycling, :can_recycling, 
  :textile_recycling,
        :diet, :pet_cost, :individual_total, :household_total,       
   :home_usage, :outdoor_usage,
        :individualDifference, :householdDifference, :vehicle_usage, 
 :power_usage, :indirect_source_usage,
        :individualDifference, :householdDifference)
    end

end
```

I currently have the following error:

```
NameError in GoalsController#create 
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for # 
<Goal:0x007fbedde9a590>
```

It seems to be in the way I am retrieving the info from the waterusage model with

```
self.household_size = @waterusage.household_size
```

It there a join I could use?

The waterusage model works BTW.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be missing the error...

Comment: NameError in GoalsController#create
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Goal:0x007fbedde9a590>

Comment: The error seems to be in the way I am trying to retrieve from waterusage with:     self.household_size = current_user.waterusage.household_size

Comment: @ezweizig: In your GoalsController, create method, this line : `@goal = current_user.create_goal(goal_params)`, where the `current_user` is coming from ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the best way to do that, but I would use something like this:

- In your goals model, you can check if its user have a waterusage already. If it has, you fill the values from that water usage

You can do it using `after_initialize` callback. In your goal model, would be something like

```
class Goal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  after_initialize :set_default_values

  def set_default_values

    waterusage = self.user.try(:waterusage)
    if waterusage

        self.attribute1 = waterusage.attribute1
        self.attribute2 = waterusage.attribute2
        self.attribute3 = waterusage.attribute3
        #and it goes on...

    end

  end

end
```

so, like this when you do a `Goal.new`, it will check for a waterusage for that user and initialize those values on your goal. So you don't have to change anything on your controller and even if you do it on console, it will work. Guess it's a better practice to do that using models callbacks. Don't know if it solves your problem, but give it a try. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is: 
    `NameError in GoalsController#create 
    undefined local variable or method`current_user' for # 
Goal:0x007fbedde9a590`

The `current_user` object is automagically defined inside your controller by the Devise gem you're using. It will **not** be defined inside your models.

One of your comments includes the following snippet you say you're using from within your Goal model: `current_user.waterusage.household_size`. That is what your error message is referring to. (Note that this snippet from one of your comments disagrees with the code in your original post. This makes it harder to be certain about what is going wrong here.)